# What is causing python nested exception error in VS Code with Click command line processor?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-click

I am using Click with Python 3.10.4 on Windows with VS Code. I have this simple test program:

```
import click

@click.group()
async def cli():
    click.echo("cli()")

@cli.command()
@click.argument('ip')
async def monitor(ip: str):
    click.echo("monitor()")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

If I run this with "python test.py monitor" it exits with an error saying missing IP argument, which is what I'd expect.

When I run it in the debugger (debugpy) within VS Code with the same command line, it comes up with the following exception message. (Exception has occurred: System Exit 2 During handling of above exception, another exception occurred)

[image]

Note: This comes up if I have any of "Raised Exceptions", "Uncaught Exceptions" or "User Uncaught Exceptions" ticked in the BREAKPOINTS windows of VS Code RUN AND DEBUG.

I'm fairly new to Python and trying to understand if this is expected. It appears to be saying that while processing SystemExit exception another exception occurred.

I'm not sure if this is a feature of Click, a bug in my code or just expected behaviour.

Is there a way to handle this more gracefully?

Comment: Also i ran your code and it works fine.  Both from the command line and in the debugger

Comment: Within VS Code on Windows? I have Uncaught User Exceptions ticked in VS breakpoints